# Google Tag Manager: fire tag on element load

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am working on a project and the site has a lot of the same pages - they are versions of the homepage. But, depending on what page you open, it will give you a different message in a lightbox.
The whole set-up is a bit strange to me, but that's what it is....

So there are countless pages, such as "~/erejib", "~/12312", "~123niwoenf123". Due to there being no fixed length, naming convention or anything, I cannot really use a regex.

However, I could say fire on all pages that contain this lightbox ID. Does Google Tag Manager support this at all?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: (By the way, this would probably be better fielded in the Webmasters forum as your question is not about coding). Do you want to track when the lightbox appears? That is possible by writing custom JS to check for the presence of that particular ID, and then configuring your rule to fire if the returned value is "true" to indicate the presence, or "false" to indicate the absence.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes, there is nothing build into Google Tag manager for this particular problem. I ended up writing all the existing pages that I want to exclude into a giant RegEx.